# cypress-looping /iterating through buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, cypress

I am new to Cypress and this is the scenario I am trying to  automate/test:
So, there is a list of buttons: some buttons say, "hello" and some say "bye".
If a button says "hello" I want it to perform further actions, and if it says "bye" then perform some other actions.
On inspecting the buttons using dev tools:

```
html
    <button class="Button__StyledButton-t5s0do-0 hZDZBR 
    OfferRequestTilestyles__StyledButton-sc-1dbu8p5-4 dRhsyx" 
    type="button">Hello</button>
```

When I use cypress selector for these buttons, then I have:

```
javascript
    cy.get(':nth-child(3) > 
    .OfferRequestTilestyles__PropertyDetailsWrapper-sc-1dbu8p5-3 > 
    .Button__StyledButton-t5s0do-0')
```

so it goes on, like nth-child(3), nth-child(4) etc and this can be dynamic, so there could be 10 buttons or 20 or 50.

Also each button is in a row which is:

```
javascript
    cy.get('.PageContainer-sc-26sn9a-0 > :nth-child(3)')
```

so nth-child(3), nth-child(4) and so on..

So for each of these buttons, check the text of the button, if its "hello" do this, if its "bye" do that.

How can I accomplish this scenario?
I read solutions online and tried this but its not the right way of doing looks like:

```
javascript
    cy.get('.OfferRequestTilestyles__PropertyDetailsWrapper-sc-1dbu8p5- 
    3')//get the page container
          .find('Button__StyledButton-t5s0do-0')
          .each(function(buttons){
           var ourButtons=buttons.text()
           cy.log("names:", ourButtons);
```

This is the error I get:

````
    'Button__StyledButton-t5s0do-0', but never found it. Queried from 
     element: [ <div.OfferRequestTilestyles__AddressWrapper-sc-1dbu8p5- 
     2.OfferRequestTilestyles__PropertyDetailsWrapper-sc-1dbu8p5- 
     3.dpPJNW>, 24 more... ]```

Thanks for help!
````

Comment: You missed out the '.' which indicate a class selector - `.find('.Button__StyledButton-t5s0do-0')`

Comment: I did! Thanks for pointing it out! It still cant find the OfferRequestTilestyles__PropertyDetailsWrapper-sc-1dbu8p5-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was successful in looping through the buttons using:

```
javascript
javascript
    cy.get('.OfferRequestTilestyles__PropertyDetailsWrapper-sc-1dbu8p5- 
    3')//get the page container
          .find('.Button__StyledButton-t5s0do-0')
          .each(function(buttons){
           var ourButtons=buttons.text()
           cy.log("names:", ourButtons);
```

Also accept Richard Matsen's answer, I had missed out on the class selector . Thanks for pointing that out Richard! It helped me!